# What is the base inheritance ancestor on DOM ie prev 8?

Tags: javascript, html, internet-explorer, dom, element

Good evening, I'm looking for a way to identify the base object on DOM for internet explorer version 8 or previous, because I need to check when a function receives common objects or htmlelements instances, but for this versions the Element prorotype is not defined. In debug mode I see there are several DispHTML(Objects), such as DispHTMLDocument, DispHTMLWindow2, DispHTMLScriptElement, etc but I cannot identify or even get closed to their common denominator.

To iexplorer 9 and newer versions, I can work with Element for type identification by using: (value instanceof Element), but how to get similar solutions for previous ie versions?

Comment: What is the higher level problem you are trying to solve?

Comment: Hi there, what I need is to identify if an object into a function is an ordinary Object {}  or html element because in iexplorer 8 and older versions Element, HtmlElement are not defined and what is peculiar is that html elements does not inherit from Object so, I need to find the base object for html elements.

Comment: The main idea is compare like:
    if(obj instanceof Element) {
        // Do something
    } else if(obj instanceof Object) {
        // Do something more interesting
    } else {
        // Do something else
    }